# Python BST search - TypeError

Tags: python, class, typeerror, nodes

I have the following class for a binary search tree node:

```
class Node: 
    # Implement a node of the binary search tree.
    # Constructor for a node with key and a given parent
    # parent can be None for a root node.
    def __init__(self, key, parent = None): 
        self.key = key
        self.parent = parent 
        self.left = None # We will set left and right child to None
        self.right = None
        # Make sure that the parent's left/right pointer
        # will point to the newly created node.
        if parent != None:
            if key < parent.key:
                assert(parent.left == None), 'parent already has a left child -- unable to create node'
                parent.left = self
            else: 
                assert key > parent.key, 'key is same as parent.key. We do not allow duplicate keys in a BST since it breaks some of the algorithms.'
                assert(parent.right == None ), 'parent already has a right child -- unable to create node'
                parent.right = self
```

I'm trying to search the tree to see if a given key exists. Here is what I have for the search function:

```
    def search(self, key):
        print("self.key: ", type(self.key), "\n", "key: ", type(key))    
        if self.key == key: 
            return (True, self)
        # your code here
        elif self.key < key:
            if self.right == None:
                return (False, self)
            else: self.search(self.right)
        elif self.key > key:
            if self.left == None:
                return (False, self)
            else: self.search(self.left)
```

However, I've tried changing the `elif` and keep getting errors. When I enter the following lines, I get the associated errors:

`elif self.key < key:` : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Node'

`elif self.key() < key:` : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

`elif key(self) < key:` : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears the `key` parameter you are passing to `search` is a `Node` object and not an integer. How do you call the function? What is the output of that `print` statement?

Comment: (b, found_node) = t1.search(18)
assert b and found_node.key == 18, 'test 8 failed'

Comment: I just noticed, you are not returning the value of the recursive calls: `else: self.search(self.right)` should be `else: return self.search(self.right)` Same with left.

Comment: Thanks, good catch! However, I'm still getting the error messages for the ```elif``` clauses.

Comment: Also, you are making the recursive calls on `self` but it should be `left` and `right`. And you need to pass the search key: `else: return self.right.search(key)`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is how you make the recursive calls.

1. You make the call on `self` when it should be `self.left` or `self.right`
2. You ignore the return value from the recursion
3. You need to pass the search key to the recursive calls

```
def search(self, key):
    if self.key == key: 
        return (True, self)
    elif self.key < key:
        if self.right == None:
            return (False, self)
        else:
            return self.right.search(key)
    else:
        if self.left == None:
            return (False, self)
        else:
            return self.left.search(key)
```